# catkin - stack.yaml does not exist

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when I manually download a catkinized package from https://github.com/ros it doesn't come with a stack.yaml file.

When I cd into that downloaded package and cmake, it then complains for the stack.yaml file not existing. I realize, stack.xml contains exactly the same information, so I manually created the yaml file from xml in order to get catkinized CMakeLists.txt work with cmake.

Right now I'm just playing with catkinized packages and their CMakeLists.txt to better understand how to catkinize my packages.

My questions is:

Is there a script to convert the stack.xml into stack.yaml?

OR when we follow the rosinstall process, is catkin reading the information from the stack.xml directly (since catkinized stacks don't have a .yaml file in them)? If so how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35378/catkin---stack.yaml-does-not-exist/) by [bener suay](https://answers.ros.org/users/1003/bener-suay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bener suay](https://answers.ros.org/users/1003/bener-suay/) on 2012-05-31**:
Hi joq, thanks for the answer. Actually it is possible to build single packages. I got it working for a package. You just have to do everything manually and if you have a lot of packages it takes time. My question is only about getting a stack.yaml from stack.xml (or manifest.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a bit of flux right now.  We have reviewed the stack.yaml usage and have determined the cost of switching too high. So we're switching back to stack.xml for catkin stacks.  It requires slightly different syntax for catkin stacks.

We're in the process of switching back to the new form of stack.xml.  Once we finish we plan to email everyone to try things out and give feedback.  Right now the trunks of most of the catkinized stacks are broken.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bener suay](https://answers.ros.org/users/1003/bener-suay/) on 2012-06-03**:
Thanks for the answer Tully. Looking forward to it.